# Why didn't Beckett just shoot everybody?

Tags: star-wars, character-motivation, solo-a-star-wars-story

Near the end of the movie *Solo: A Star Wars Story*, Tobias Beckett...

> betrays Han and works with Dryden to deliver the coaxium. Once he realizes Dryden's mini-army has been disposed of, he shoots Dryden's guards and takes the coaxium for himself. He leaves Dryden, Han, and Qi'Ra there in the room.

I understand his reason for not leaving Chewbacca was,

> because Chewbacca could carry his coaxium for him.

**But why not kill the rest**?

Tobias clearly had the upper hand, the others were defenseless, and he'd already proven himself disloyal to any of them.

Comment: Well Han Solo has to survive to _A New Hope_, so he couldn't die. and killing the other two but leaving Han is just bad sportsmanship.

Comment: Killing Han will cause Chewie go on a rampage. Killing Qi'Ra will make Han and Dryden go on a Rampage after him. Killing Dryden will make Han go after him (with Qi'Ra probably helping). So the only move to keep all three of them of his back might be leaving them to fight each other.

Comment: @Adwaenyth Yeah, maybe. But that seems a little too idealistic. I don't think Becket, the one with the blaster that just killed three guards, was too worried about someone's unarmed rampage.

Comment: @LCIII The main kicker is that he needs Chewie and having him on his bad side is probably not such a good idea, especially considering what Becket needs him to carry. So he cannot kill Han. If he cannot kill Han, well the rest falls mostly into place considering Becket and Chewie will be on foot for a while and the others are still on Dryden's Yacht.

Comment: @Edlothiad But if he did shoot Han, that could create the SW equivalent of the Kelvin timeline, allowing George to write a whole new set of movies!

Comment: Han was shot first!

Answer (score 4):

I think that one of the reasons why he did not shoot everybody who was there was because he saw Han Solo develop a friendship with Chewbacca, who is a Wookiee; and during the movie he had a good friend who was also his pilot, and he may not have wanted to make Chewbacca lose his good friend like he had.

Also, he lost the love of his life while they were trying to get the Coaxium off the train, and he may have taken pity on Han and not made him lose the love of his life, and he is kind of ashamed of himself for an unknown reason, so he would want others to live a better life than he did.